# AWS SDK for PHPを使ってS3に画像をアップロードする

Tags: cakephp, aws, amazon-s3

タイトル通りなのですが、CakePHP3にAWS SDK for PHPをインストールし、それを使ってAWSのS3にインストールしようしています。

```php
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    require('/var/www/html/imagine/src/vendor/autoload.php');   

    use App\Controller\AppController;

    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

    use Aws;
    use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;     
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
    use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
    use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
    use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;

    use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

class ImagesController extends AppController {
    public function upload(){

        $end_point_url = '*******';

        $client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                          'key' => '******',
                          'secret'  => '*****',
                      ),
            "region" => 'ap_northeast_1',
            "version" => '2006-03-01',
            'base_url' => "$end_point_url"
        ));


        $tmpfile = "/var/www/html/test.jpg";

        // バケット名
        $bucket = "s3-bucket-imagine";
        // アップロードファイル名
        $key = "test1.jpg";

        $uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, "$tmpfile", [
                'bucket' => "$bucket",
                'key'    => "$key"
        ]);
        //debug($uploader);

        try {
                $result = $uploader->upload();
                echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n";
        } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";　//←!!!!!!!
        }
    }
}
?>
```

upload()でエラーが発生し、`echo $e->getMessage()`で以下のような表示されます。

```
An exception occurred while initiating a multipart upload.
```

`$uploader->upload()`でエラーが発生しているのは間違いないのですが、
現状そのエラーを解決することができません。

なにかありましたら、随時補足いたしますのでよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/19255 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リージョン文字列が正しくないのではないでしょうか。

`'ap_northeast_1'` → `'ap-northeast-1'` もしくは `Region::AP_NORTHEAST_1`

Answer (score 1):

```
$client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
            'profile' => 'default',
            'key' => '******',
            'secret' => '******',
            'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1',
    ));
```

という書き方でどうですか？